# Context propagation in Temporal

Tags: temporal-workflow

**Context:**

I have an application using Temporal and Spring Boot where i want to propagate the JWT of the user who started the workflow to activities, so that the token is propagated across API calls leaving my service. For that purpose I am using `ContextPropagator` from the Java SDK.

In my context propagtor, `setCurrentContext` uses `SecurityContextHolder` of Spring Security to store the token. `SecurityContextHolder` uses under the hood a `ThreadLocal` variable.
`getCurrentContext` fetches the token from `SecurityContextHolder` and then **clears the SecurityContext**. I am clearing the SecurityContext since to my understanding, there is no guarantee that the thread currently being used to execute the workflow will continue the execution once an activity is called and done processing and might actually start executing a different workflow. So in order to avoid leaking the `SecurityContext` across workflows re-using the same thread, I am clearing the security context upon any call to Temporal, more specifically: upon calling `getCurrentContext`.

**Problem:**
The context is not being propagated upon activity completion. Example:

```
class MyWorkflow implements IMyWorkflow {
    private FirstActivity firstActivity = Workflow.newActivityStub(FirstActivity.class);
    private SecondActivity secondActivity = Workflow.newActivityStub(SecondActivity.class);


    @Override
    void execute() {
        // SecurityContext exists here and is propagated correctly to FirstActivity
        firstActivity.doSomething();
        // SecurityContext is empty here
        secondActivity.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Taking a closer look at the events in Temporal, I noticed that the headers of the `ActivityTaskCompleted` and the following `WorkflowTaskScheduled` are empty, and do not hold the same context that was set upon `ActivityTaskScheduled`.

**Question:**
Is this behavior intended? How would the propagation work in case a different thread continued the workflow execution after an activity execution is completed? How can we guarantee that any static variable set during context propagation is correct if we cannot clear it upon propagating the context?

Comment: I think that if you want to clear the context, you have to use interceptors instead of context propagators. Interceptors give you the ability to run code both before and after executing the intercepted call, so you can safely clear your thread locals after executing each activity without affecting subsequent activity calls.

Comment: @dano but how does temporal guarantee that the thread used to run the workflow will not end up picking up a different workflow in case we are not clearing the context? If the thread actuallly started executing a different workflow, the context will be leaked to another workflow, and for my use case (authorization) this leads to security issues in my services